# urlsafe_b64decode: return binascii.a2b_base64(s)

Tags: python, cryptography, base64

I'm working on python `cryptography` by following [tutorial](https://nitratine.net/blog/post/encryption-and-decryption-in-python/).

here is the code:

```
import os 
import base64
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.kdf.pbkdf2 import PBKDF2HMAC

BASE_DESTINATION = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
KEY_DESTINATION = os.path.join(BASE_DESTINATION, 'keys/')

def generate_key_from_password(path = KEY_DESTINATION):
    passwordProvided = str(input("Enter Password: ")) # enter your password
    password = passwordProvided.encode()
    salt =  os.urandom(16)
    # salt = b'aeroplane'
    
    kdf = PBKDF2HMAC(
        algorithm= hashes.SHA256(),
        length= 32,
        salt= salt,
        iterations= 100_000,
        backend = default_backend()
    )
    key = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(kdf.derive(password)) # generated successed!
    
    print("key: ", key)
   generate_key_from_password()
```

when key is generated with `base64.urlsafe_b64decode(kdf.derive(password))` I get error: `binascii.Error: Invalid base64-encoded string: number of data characters (5) cannot be 1 more than a multiple of 4`

I visited many answers but nothing quite really fit for my code. ie: I added `'='` and `'=='` to password string to solve padding problem and adding padding by calculation `password = str(password) + ('=' * len(password))` and but it didn't work either.

Here is the full error:

```
Enter Password: pass

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gfp.py", line 33, in <module>
    generate_key_from_password()
  File "gfp.py", line 28, in generate_key_from_password
    key = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(kdf.derive(password)) # generated successed!
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\IRIS-REC\lib\base64.py", line 133, in urlsafe_b64decode
    return b64decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\IRIS-REC\lib\base64.py", line 87, in b64decode

    return binascii.a2b_base64(s)
binascii.Error: Invalid base64-encoded string: number of data characters (5) cannot be 1 more than a multiple of 4
```

Comment: Try `base64.urlsafe_b64encode(...)`.

Comment: OMG!!! @Topaco thank you. It solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is provided by @Topaco in the comments.  (Thank you!)

The problem was in the syntax.

it should be `base64.urlsafe_b64encode(...)` instead of `base64.urlsafe_b64decode(kdf.derive(password))`. I've seen the code multiple times but somehow I missed this everytime.

Thank you @topaco